# Sometimes vim mappings inserts chars instead of executing commands

Tags: vim

Some of my mappings, instead of executing the commands I want, will print some chars. Looks like  sometimes won't be executed fast enough. It usually happens when I am programming typing fast and after expanding a method.

Take for instance this mapping:

```
inoremap <leader>s <ESC>:w<cr>
```

Pretend "|" (pipe) is where the cursor is.

Suppose I am writing a method, like this:

```
public function something()
{|
```

Then I hit enter and the code expands to

```
public function something()
{
    |
}
```

Then I keep implementing:

```
public function something()
{
    return "something|"
}
```

And when execute `<leader>s` the file in that position the code turns into something like:

```
public function something()
{
    return "something:w
"
}
```

This is so annoying. My vimrc is [here](https://github.com/mjacobus/.dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc). Perhaps that has to do with some plugin, but I don't really know how to find out whats happening or how to debug. When I try to reproduce the error I can get it done, because it is random. It will just work fine most times.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I didn't go through all of them nor did I try. 1. white space matters remove excess whitespace from your mappings. 2. Use noremap versions of map unless you really know what you are doing. 3. Set up vundle properly.

Comment: By 1 - whitespaces you mean the leading spaces for indentation? It must not be that, cause I have had this problem for a very long time, and my first vimrc versions did not have any indentation. I will try removing the non nonrecursive mappings. Thank you! @FDinoff

Comment: I was talking about the white space in mappings and after (even if you can't see it). Leading whitespace does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `i[nore]map` for insert mode mapping. Well, always use mode-specific mapping commands:

```
" insert mode mapping
inoremap <leader>s <esc>:w<cr>
```

Quiz: what does the first letter mean in the mappings below?

```
n[nore]map <key> something
x[nore]map <key> something
c[nore]map <key> something
```

Comment: this is actually what I have. Except that I had 2 mappings, one noremap and one inoremap. The first one was supposed to be Nnoremap, for normal mode. I don't know what is the Xnoremap... well, lets see, perhaps the change I made will male it work. Tks!

Comment: Even if this is an example. Don't put comments after the mapping.

Comment: @Marcelo, `inoremap <leader>s <esc>:w<cr>` works perfectly, here. Try bisecting your config to see if there's a problem somewhere else.

Comment: @romainl I tried to disable groups of plugins, a few at a time. Looks like [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) is causing it and now I am trying the code of [this](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs/pull/84) pull request. Lets see.

Comment: Yeah, it was an auto-pairs issue. I changed the source repo of the plugin and the strange behaviour stopped.